# UEFI not detecting a PCIe drive

Tags: boot, ssd, uefi, pci-express

I'm trying to setup a computer with the AsRock J3455-ITX motherboard and a mSATA SSD through a PCIe to mSATA adapter as the boot device (I'm using all the other 4 SATA slots for drives I don't want to boot from). Debian let me install the system on the SSD without any problems, but now I cannot boot from it as UEFI doesn't detect it at all.

Is there a solution other than changing the hardware configuration?

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of that “PCIe to mSATA adapter”.

Comment: @DanielB Not sure if this will provide the information needed as I bought some noname off eBay at: https://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-PCIe-to-mSATA-SSD-SATA3-0-Combo-Extender-Adapter-PCI-E-toSATAIII-Card-3/263561829282?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: Yes, this information is enough, it names the chipset used (ASM1061). Unfortunately, I didn’t find reliable information on whether this SATA controller supports booting at all, neither negative nor positive. As such, I’m reluctant to answer the question. // One last question for clarification though: Do you want to boot using UEFI mode or using BIOS mode?

Comment: @DanielB I would prefer UEFI, however I don't insist on either.